# How to remove Action Bar and set the custom title of FragmentActivity of Sherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-fragmentactivity

Hello I am using Sherlock library to achieve the `Tabs`. Here I am looking to remove the `ActionBar` at the top and set the custom title layout instead of it.

I achieved a functionality to add the `Tabs` but could not set the custom title over `ActionBar.` Any way to do this ?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay_stub);

    // adding action bar tabs to the activity
    ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    Tab firstTab = mActionBar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.paystub_current_tab)).setTabListener(this);
    Tab secondTab = mActionBar.newTab().setText(getString(R.string.paystub_all_tab)).setTabListener(this);

    // add the tabs to the action bar
    mActionBar.addTab(firstTab);
    mActionBar.addTab(secondTab);

    // set the navigation mode the Action Bar Tabs
    mActionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding background color and icon of the `ActionBar`.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
setTitle("");
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.headerlogo);
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#F4A401")));
```